# Cumulative mod_rewrite rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm having trouble understanding the mod_rewrite condictions and rules workflow.
despite reading this very nice tutorial `http://craym.eu/tutoriels/referencement/url_rewriting.html.` I can't perform the job I need :

here is my htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^entreprise(.*)$ feerie$1


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Here is what I'm searching for in that file  :

- second rule, the simplest one (it works when it is alone), All the time rewrite

  - `www.example.com/foo -> www.example.com/index.php?/foo`.
  - This is a codeigniter framework rule.

  .
- the first rule in the file should rewrite :

  - `www.example.com/entreprise -> www.example.com/feerie`
  - and after that the second rule should rewrite
  - `www.example.com/feerie ->  www.example.com/index.php?/feerie`

here what I have in the rewrite.log :

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2014:17:46:49 +0100] [www.example.com/sid#b73910][rid#e4a8f0/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /entreprise
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2014:17:46:49 +0100] [www.example.com/sid#b73910][rid#e4a8f0/initial] (1) pass through /entreprise
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2014:17:46:49 +0100] [www.example.com/sid#b73910][rid#e4a8f0/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Users/NICOLAS/example/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Users/NICOLAS/example/entreprise -> entreprise
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2014:17:46:49 +0100] [www.example.com/sid#b73910][rid#e4a8f0/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Users/NICOLAS/example/] applying pattern '^entreprise(.*)$' to uri 'entreprise'
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2014:17:46:49 +0100] [www.example.com/sid#b73910][rid#e4a8f0/initial] (2) [perdir C:/Users/NICOLAS/example/] rewrite 'entreprise' -> 'feerie'
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2014:17:46:49 +0100] [www.example.com/sid#b73910][rid#e4a8f0/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Users/NICOLAS/example/] add per-dir prefix: feerie -> C:/Users/NICOLAS/example/feerie
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2014:17:46:49 +0100] [www.example.com/sid#b73910][rid#e4a8f0/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Users/NICOLAS/example/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Users/NICOLAS/example/feerie -> feerie
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2014:17:46:49 +0100] [www.example.com/sid#b73910][rid#e4a8f0/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Users/NICOLAS/example/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'feerie'
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2014:17:46:49 +0100] [www.example.com/sid#b73910][rid#e4a8f0/initial] (2) [perdir C:/Users/NICOLAS/example/] rewrite 'feerie' -> 'index.php?/feerie'
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2014:17:46:49 +0100] [www.example.com/sid#b73910][rid#e4a8f0/initial] (3) split uri=index.php?/feerie -> uri=index.php, args=/feerie
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2014:17:46:49 +0100] [www.example.com/sid#b73910][rid#e4a8f0/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Users/NICOLAS/example/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> C:/Users/NICOLAS/example/index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2014:17:46:49 +0100] [www.example.com/sid#b73910][rid#e4a8f0/initial] (2) [perdir C:/Users/NICOLAS/example/] strip document_root prefix: C:/Users/NICOLAS/example/index.php -> /index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2014:17:46:49 +0100] [www.example.com/sid#b73910][rid#e4a8f0/initial] (1) [perdir C:/Users/NICOLAS/example/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2014:17:46:49 +0100] [www.example.com/sid#b73910][rid#ea49b0/initial/redir#1] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2014:17:46:49 +0100] [www.example.com/sid#b73910][rid#ea49b0/initial/redir#1] (1) pass through /index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2014:17:46:49 +0100] [www.example.com/sid#b73910][rid#ea49b0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Users/NICOLAS/example/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Users/NICOLAS/example/index.php -> index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2014:17:46:49 +0100] [www.example.com/sid#b73910][rid#ea49b0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Users/NICOLAS/example/] applying pattern '^entreprise(.*)$' to uri 'index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2014:17:46:49 +0100] [www.example.com/sid#b73910][rid#ea49b0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Users/NICOLAS/example/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Users/NICOLAS/example/index.php -> index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2014:17:46:49 +0100] [www.example.com/sid#b73910][rid#ea49b0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Users/NICOLAS/example/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2014:17:46:49 +0100] [www.example.com/sid#b73910][rid#ea49b0/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir C:/Users/NICOLAS/example/] pass through C:/Users/NICOLAS/example/index.php
```

Comment: Why not just rewrite the first rule to `index.php?/feerie`?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I tryied the following : `RewriteRule ^entreprise(.*)$ index.php?/feerie$1 [L]` But I keep having this INTERNAL REDIRECT in my logs... is it normal ?

Comment: Adding a [R] I get redirected from `http://www.example.com/entreprise`  to `http://www.example.com/C:/Users/NICOLAS/example/index.php?/feerie` SOO  FRUSTRATING

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the beginning seems to work :

```
RewriteBase /
```

Here is the full file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^entreprise(.*)$ index.php?/feerie$1 [R,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]


</IfModule>
```

Can someone explain that to me ?